# strange zsh segfault glitch with function definitions

Tags: unix, terminal, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I find this really neat, but I'm not involved enough to figure out what's happening.

Does anyone know why this behavior exists in zsh, or what zsh is trying to do that causes a segfault?

```
➜  ~  (echo "hi"(); echo "hi"; echo "hi")
[1]    65962 segmentation fault  ( echo "hi" () { ... }; echo "hi"; )

➜  ~  (ls(); ls; ls)
[1]    66073 segmentation fault  ( ls -G () { ... }; ls -G; )
```

I put it in a subprocess so that it prints out what happens; otherwise, if you, for example, run `ls()`, then fill in `function>` with `ls`, then run ls again, it crashes the terminal.

It only happens when you try to redefine functions with themselves, like echo `str1(); echo str2`, but not `ls(); echo str`. It does not work with every possible input, but only because of syntax parsing, for example, although:

```
➜  ~  (^A(); ^A; ^A)
[1]    66154 segmentation fault  ( ^A () { ... }; ^A; )
```

this does not work for syntax reasons if you run it line by line:

```
➜  ~  ^A()
zsh: substitution failed
```

Strangely enough, behavior like this occurs:

```
➜  ~  a()
function> 7
➜  ~  a
a:cd:3: no such entry in dir stack
➜  ~  8()
function> b
➜  ~  8
cd:7: command not found: b
➜  ~  9()
function> 13
➜  ~  9
cd:6: command not found: 13
```

BUT

```
➜  ~  9()
function> 5
➜  ~  (9)
[1]    66979 segmentation fault  ( cd -9; )
```

which would crash the terminal if not in a subprocess, meaning that *you can define a single digit number as a function that directs to a double-digit number, but not to a single-digit one*! This is equivalent for letters (`c(); a` is a segfault maker, `c(); bh` is a "no command found"). `71(); 81; 71;` also does not cause a segfault.

I'm very curious about what is going wrong under the hood! It does provide an obnoxious way of messing with people, since putting

```
echo $JAVA_HOME()
echo "hi"
```

in `.zshrc` will crash the terminal even if someone only attempts to *use* $JAVA_HOME in, say, a variable assignment, it will cause a segfault, e.g.,

```
➜  ~  ($JAVA_HOME)
[1]    66745 segmentation fault  ( $JAVA_HOME; )    
➜  ~  (X= $JAVA_HOME)
[1]    66737 segmentation fault  ( X= $JAVA_HOME; )
```

Perhaps this also calls for a patch down the line, since I can imagine there could be some exploitation of this for rude purposes. Is this a known problem?

It doesn't work in bash because of how bash parses function definitions.

Comment: The `(echo hi(); echo hi; echo hi)` thing might be a bug, but about single and double digit: your single digits are probably all aliased to `cd +$digit` (or `cd -$digit`). Check `alias 1`, `alias 2`, ..., `alias 9` and you'll realize it's a trick from your configuration framework (in Prezto it's in `directory`). Still it's unclear to me why that would trigger a segfault; probably also a bug. Report to zsh-workers@zsh.org.

Comment: You really should file a bug at zs-workers@zsh.org

Comment: Please notice that there a segfault is a bug. Plain and simple. The shell should print an error if the syntax is wrong or when the user does funny things, not crash.